# Astrology signs?

Tags: symbols, packages

Is there any package that has ALL the 12 zodiac signs of astrology? I tried `wasysym` but it doesn't display "Capricorn", at least not in my computer (Windows 7, TexStudio 2.3, MikTex 2.8)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add an example of what you're doing in order to get the symbol?

Comment: `wasysym` should work, though. The zodiacal symbols are also included in the `marvosym` package and can be accessed either with `\Aries`... `\Pisces` or with `\Zodiac{1}`... `\Zodiac{12}`.

Comment: The command for capricorn in wasysym is `\capricornus` and it works fine for me (miktex 2.9.).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This website [Detexify²](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can help you to identify commands for particular latex symbols by drawing them.

The first two raised by my drawing were `\capricornus` from the *wasysym* package and `\Capricorn` from the *marvosym* package.

Comment: That's why `\capricorn` wasn't working! Thank you very much. Silly me...

Answer (score 13):

As already said, the symbols are in both package `wasysym` and package `marvosym`.
They can also be found in the [**The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List**](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage[unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}[2012/08/13]%
% [2012/09/04]% v6.83e contains fix for \capricornus
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand*{\entry}[2]{%
  \pdfbookmark{%
    \csname #1\endcsname/\csname #2\endcsname\space
    (\textbackslash #1/\textbackslash #2)%
  }{#1/#2}%
  \ttfamily \textbackslash #1
  & \csname #1\endcsname
  & \csname #2\endcsname
  & \ttfamily \textbackslash #2
  \tabularnewline
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll|ll@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{@{}r|}{\textsf{wasysym}}&
\multicolumn{2}{l@{}}{\textsf{marvosym}}\\
\hline
\entry{aries}{Aries}
\entry{taurus}{Taurus}
\entry{gemini}{Gemini}
\entry{cancer}{Cancer}
\entry{leo}{Leo}
\entry{virgo}{Virgo}
\entry{libra}{Libra}
\entry{scorpio}{Scorpio}
\entry{sagittarius}{Sagittarius}
\entry{capricornus}{Capricorn}
\entry{aquarius}{Aquarius}
\entry{pisces}{Pisces}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Astrology signs with wasysym and marvosym]

The symbols are also supported in bookmarks with package `hyperref` (option `unicode`/`psdencoding=auto` and option `psdextra` except for `\capricornus` that will be fixed in v6.83e:

> [image: Astrology signs in bookmarks of AR10/Win]

Comment: `wasysym` permits characters to be in the subscript but not `marvosym`

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu `wasysym` puts its symbols in `\mbox` to force text mode. Therefore, they can be used in math, but the size does not change in the sub- or superscript. `marvosym` defines text mode symbols. In both cases, the symbols can be used with `\text` (package `amsmath` or `amstext`), for example: `$A_{\text{\aries}} = A_{\text{\Aries}}$`