# Draw zodiac sign leo

Tags: tikz-pgf

tikz community,

after hours of seeking a solution to draw the zodiac sign leo I realize that I cannot deal with finding control points to get a wished curve. I tried bend-to and others, no result. I have fixed approx coordinates to show the idea of the wished line. Can anyone help? I do not add a photo because of copyrights, but I think there is no difficulty to get an image of this sign beyond artistic freedom. If possible I want to do it in tikz.

The mwe ist somewhat rediculous. As I have said, I cannot realize it.

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{
                   }
    \usepackage[paperheight=160mm,paperwidth=180mm,top=5mm,bottom=5mm,left=5mm,right=5mm,showframe]{geometry}
    \tikzset{%
      >=latex, % option for nice arrows
      inner sep=0pt,%
      outer sep=2pt,%
      mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt,fill=black,circle}%
    }
    \begin{document}
    % leo
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=0.5cm,help lines] (-2,-2) grid (3,4);
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1.5,...,3}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {-2,-1.5,...,4}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
    %
    \draw[line width=4mm, line cap=round] (0,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=6mm];
    %
    \filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt]; %
    \filldraw          [red]       (1,0) circle [radius=2pt];
    \filldraw          [blue]       (2,1) circle [radius=2pt];
    \filldraw          [green]       (2,0) circle [radius=2pt];
    %
    
    \draw[line width=4mm, line cap=round] (0,0.5) 
                                          to[bend left=100] (0,3)
                                          to[bend left=100] (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (l1) at (0.5,0);
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (l2) at (1.0,0.5);
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (l3) at (0.5,1);
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (l4) at (0.0,0.5);
         \draw (l1) -- (l2) -- (l3) -- (l4)  --(l1);
         % line leaves the "circle" between l2 and l3
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (gb0) at (0.75,0.75);
         % building a great bow. no circle
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (gb1) at (0.5,2.0);
         \draw (gb0) -- (gb1);
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (gb2) at (1.5,2.5);
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (gb3) at (2.0,2.0);
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (gb4) at (1.55,-0.25);
         \draw (gb1) -- (gb2) -- (gb3) -- (gb4);
         % last bow to the right
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (lb1) at (1.75,-0.45);
         \coordinate [mark coordinate] (lb2) at (2.0,-0.25);
         \draw (gb4) -- (lb1) -- (lb2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot reedit the garbled salutation :-(

Comment: Why don't you use package `wasysym` which has the command `\leo`? See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70066/astrology-signs

Comment: I do not know it. and I have to import it, which makes me great difficulties. So a handmade solution would be better to familiarize with the concept of drawing curved lines.

Comment: My system finds wasysym - typo error, my fault. I take a look.

Comment: @CarlaTex The look is unchangeable. I need a self-made one. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You got various solutions, anyway :)

Answer (score 6):

Several fonts have astronomical symbols. In general you can consult the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), which, even though it is quite long, is easily searchable. You'll find the characters of interest in Tables 325–331.

With `\usepackage{starfont}` the command `\Leo` produces:

[image]

With `wasysym` the command is `\leo`:

[image]

`marvosym` has `\Leo`:

[image]

The package `utfsym` has `\usym{264C}`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your hints, good source, but I need a self-made one or a way to manipulate the symbols.

Answer (score 4):

A quick start point could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2mm]
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \draw (30:1) to[out=120,in=270] (0.5,2) to[out=90,in=180] (1.5,3) to[out=0,in=90] (2.5,2) to [out=270,in=180] (2.5,-2) arc (270:315:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many, many variables. Changing one all is disturbed. I hope a more handy solution would be better. But nevertheless thank you.

Comment: This could be done as a `pic`, and then no more problem when you try and change placement and/or size.

Answer (score 4):

**The finished.**

Example 4: From http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

in Table 330, the statement
**All utfsym symbols are implemented with TikZ graphics, not with a font**, so, if your symbol is not a font, then of course `texpath` will not be able to describe it. It means that `texpath` does not work for the `utfsym` package or similar packages!

From CarLaTeX's comment.

If you know [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/), you will find that it has several amazing commands!

The command is `path[] texpath(Label L)` (the path array that TEX would fill to
draw the Label L.). You can test many other LaTeX symbols.

```
usepackage("wasysym");
size(350,0);

path[] g=texpath("\leo");
write(g.length); // Outputs: 2

filldraw(g[0],cyan+green,red+dashed+.8bp);
filldraw(g[1],gray,blue+1.5bp);

write(cyclic(g[0])); // Outputs: true
write(cyclic(g[1])); // Outputs: true

arrow("the red and dashed path ",relpoint(g[0],0.78),dir(90));
arrow("the blue path which has the linewidth is 1.5bp",relpoint(g[1],0),dir(-90));
```

[image]

or with `\cancer`

```
usepackage("wasysym");
size(350,0);

path[] g=texpath("\cancer");
write(g.length); // Outputs: 4

filldraw(g[1],gray,blue+1.5bp);
filldraw(g[0],cyan+green,red+dashed+.8bp);
filldraw(g[3],gray,blue+1.5bp);
filldraw(g[2],cyan+green,red+dashed+.8bp);

write(cyclic(g[0])); // Outputs: true
write(cyclic(g[1])); // Outputs: true
write(cyclic(g[2])); // Outputs: true
write(cyclic(g[3])); // Outputs: true
```

[image]

You can handle the curves manually!

**RUN *Asymptote codes* in Notepad++ on MSWindows system.**

Step 1: Install [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/).

Step 2:
Install TeXLive (recommended by Asymptote's authors), Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, Asymptote (latest version), Ghostscript (stable version), ImageMagick (stable version).

Step 3:
Add two following files:

[asy.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14PtLN51EOv6da2oY4vGQHE_N7xbIHfM5/view?usp=sharing) is belong to ..\Notepad++\autoCompletion

[userDefineLang.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UJCPNM5XdPJmI9GpKPaUJGeMD2oaMhRO/view?usp=sharing) is belong to ..\PC\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++

To update new commands, see following links:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/asy4cn/downloads (in Chinese)
https://asy.marris.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?t=148 (in French)

Sorry, my native language is Vietnamese, I also know a little English.

These are my several pictures after installing successfully.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Run [latexusage.tex](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/LaTeX-usage.html#LaTeX-usage) in TeXstudio:**

Like this, the file name is `document.tex`
[image]

You run step by step as follows:

1. `Tools --> Commands --> PDFLaTeX`, the output like this
   [image]
2. `Tools --> Commands --> Asymptote`, the output like this
   [image]
3. `Tools --> Commands --> PDFLaTeX`, done.

The completed file lies in C:\Users\PC\Downloads as in attached images.
[image]

You can also choose http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ to compile Asymptote code online.

You must compile any Asymptote codes successfully, then you can start with Asymptote.

You can try to install Notepad++ on Linux! If done, feel free to update this answer.

To make clear my opinion `You can handle the curves manually!`:

Example 1: [Can I visualize the Bezier control points of a letter ... in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178978/236162)

Example 2: [Animated filling of a font character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/556895/236162)

Example 3:

```
// settings.render=8;
unitsize(1cm);

import texcolors; // for pens like CornflowerBlue, Goldenrod,Bittersweet, Melon

texpreamble("\usepackage{starfont}");
path[] h=texpath("\Leo");

// To know the number of paths of Label L in texpath
write(h.length); // Outputs: 2

fill(h[1],pink+opacity(.5));
filldraw(h[0],CornflowerBlue,red+1.5bp); 
pair[] P;   
for(int j=0;j<size(h[0]);++j){ P.push(point(h[0],j)); } 
pair interpoint=extension(P[0],P[2],P[1],P[3]); 
for (int j=0; j<P.length; ++j){ 
  dot("$P["+(string) j+"]$",P[j],dir(j*90)); 
}  
filldraw(shift(interpoint)*scale(0.75)*shift(-interpoint)*h[0],CornflowerBlue+yellow,red+1.5bp);

real[] c=uniform(0,length(h[1]),5);
write(c); // Outputs: {0,4,8,12,16,20}
c.cyclic=true;

pen[] pp={YellowGreen+dashdotted+1bp,blue+dashed+1bp,dotted+1.5bp,Goldenrod+0.6bp,Bittersweet+0.7bp,Melon+0.8bp};

for (int i=0; i<c.length-1; ++i)
  draw(subpath(h[1],c[i],c[i+1]),pp[i],Arrow(size=10));

draw((0,0)--(5,0),Arrow);
draw((5,0)--(-5,4),Arrow);
dot("$(0,0)$",(0,0),dir(90));
dot("$(5,0)$",(5,0),dir(0));
dot("$(-5,4)$",(-5,4),dir(90));

pair[] interpoints=intersectionpoints(h[1],(0,0)--(5,0)--(-5,4),sqrtEpsilon);
write(interpoints.length); // Outputs: 6

dot("$A$",interpoints[0]);
dot("$B$",interpoints[1]);
dot("$C$",interpoints[2]);
dot("$D$",interpoints[3]);
dot("$E$",interpoints[4]);
dot("$F$",interpoints[5]);
```

[image]

Comment: Looks very great. Pkg Asymptote was found by latexpdf, but to use the code special handling is necessary, so a call to "asy" I have found in texdoc Asymptote. So I have to implement it all. Than a call syntax is necessary too... So I cannot use it. Perhaps later, later.

Comment: +1 Very good. Bọn cơ hội?

Comment: It would be great if you can give a mwe. In best case with the necessary commandlines and showing a case where  and how you manipulate the curves manually.

Comment: @gizeh Can you tell more details about what `showing a case where and how you manipulate the curves manually` is?

Comment: @NguyenVanChi  The Leo symbol as you drew it above is too symmetrical about the Y-axis. Because of this it may be confused with the North-Node symbol.

Comment: @Trunk You should have a look the second symbol in Sandy G's answer above.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi The command  "path[] texpath(Label L)" seems to deliver many variables to use. A mwe that shows access to the available vars would be nice. In short: Only a copy-paste mwe, which is executable makes sense for me. You have mentioned yourself "You can handle the curves manually!". Show that would be nice.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi At last, if necessary, and I think it is, some commandline instructions are necessary to run pdflatex with asymptote. The doc of asymptote is not very clear imho. So an executable mwe with the needed cmd lines would be best.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998  I have and I don't think that that it a good (i.e. unambiguous) selection either - although the other symbols (#1, #3 and #4) in Sandy G's answer are okay.

Comment: @gizeh See my updated answer. After you compiling Asymptote codes successfully, I will continue update a new example to make clear my opinion "You can handle the curves manually!".

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 I'm running primarily on Linux. So I need the input for CLI as mentioned in "texdoc asymptote". Because there are unclarities imho. And, as usual here, a mwe. Sorry and thank you for your effort.

Comment: @gizeh See my updated answer.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998  Nice job. Maybe a smaller blue circle.

Comment: @Trunk See my updated answer.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998  Việt Nam muôn năm!

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 What is needed is a tikz-example which visualizes the bezier points with coordinates. To get the glyphs is another problem. Thank you for the links (bezier curves).

Comment: @gizeh Sorry, I am not an expert about TikZ. All my examples are in `Asymptote`. If TikZ `can` !? do this, I think you will get an answer from anyone, otherwise you will get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from Asymptote's service representing a glyph's bezier control points(BCP) I was able to reproduce curves with approximately correct BCPs. Mathematically unfamiliar it was a great help to see Asymptote's delivery of BCPs. So a good answer seems to be: "Take a book of mathematics or train your use of control points.".

Unsolved is the point 25 at (0,0) of a foreach loop and the unability to fill the drawn area. Should I ask a new question?

mwe

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{
                   }
    \usepackage{wasysym} % three pkgs with Leo signs
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage{utfsym}
    \usepackage[paperheight=160mm,
                paperwidth=180mm,
                top=5mm,
                bottom=5mm,
                left=5mm,
                right=5mm,
                %showframe
               ]{geometry}
    \tikzset{%s
      inner sep=0pt,%
      outer sep=2pt,%
      mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=00pt,}%mark=x}%
    }
    \begin{document}
    wasysym \leo and marvosym \Leo and usym \usym{264C}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    % a grid
    \draw[step=.1cm,gray!50!white,very thin] (0,0) grid (8,10);
    \draw[step=1cm,black!40!red, very thin,opacity=0.4] (0,0) grid (8,10);
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {0,4,8}
       \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny$\xtext$};
    \foreach \y/\ytext in {1,5,10}
       \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {\tiny$\ytext$};
    % end grid
    % The sign maximized
    \node[outer sep=0,
          anchor=south west,
          opacity=0.5
         ] at (0,0) {\Huge\color{red!50!white}\usymH{264C}{10cm}};
    % All Points
    \foreach \px/\py [count=\c] in {%
       0.000 /4.000,
       1.900 /5.920,     
       1.900 /5.363,
       0.560 /4.000,
       1.950 /2.627,  % p5
       3.230 /4.000,  % p6
       2.800 /5.350,  % p7
       1.956 /7.600,  % p8
       4.550 /10.00,  % p9         
       7.255 /7.500,  % p10
       6.125 /4.000,  % p11
       5.700 /0.825,  % p12
       7.380 /1.260,  % p13
       7.822 /0.792,  % p14
       6.200 /0.000,  % p15
       4.580 /1.350,  % p16
       5.770 /5.000,  % p17
       6.521 /7.500,  % p18
       4.550 /9.380,  % p19
       2.685 /7.600,  % p20
       3.550 /5.000,  % p21
       3.845 /4.000,  % p22
       1.950 /2.070,  % p23
       0.000 /4,000   % p24
      }{%
       \coordinate[mark coordinate,] (p\c) at (\px,\py);
       \node[label={[left]{\tiny \c}}] 
            at (p\c) {\tiny$\times$};% {};% 
    }
    % All Controlpoints 2 at a time
    \foreach \cpx/\cpy/\cppx/\cppy [count=\c] in {%
       0     /5.15    /0.93 /5.925,   % cp1   cpp1
       2.15  /5.80    /2.15 /5.50,    % cp2   cpp2
       1.145 /5.363   /0.56 /4.80,    % cp3   cpp3
       0.51  /3.28    /1.17 /2.58,    % cp4   cpp4
       2.725 /2.625   /3.25 /3.35,    % cp5   cpp5
       3.175 /4.855   /2.82 /5.275,   % cp6   cpp6
       2.480 /5.800   /2.00 /6.550,   % cp7   cpp7
       1.956 /8.890   /2.92 /10.00,   % cp8   cpp8
       6.18  /10.0    /7.25 /8.890,   % cp9   cpp9
       7.25  /6.15    /6.78 /5.40,    % cp10  cpp10
       5.125 /1.80    /5.125/1.30,    % cp11  cpp11
       6.25  /0.48    /6.800/0.75,    % cp12  cpp12
       7.75  /1.45    /8.025/1.130,   % cp13  cpp13
       6.99  /0.030   /6.490/0.030,   % cp14  cpp14
       5.42  /0.000   /4.717/0.485,   % cp15  cpp15
       4.55  /2.290   /4.825/3.000,   % cp16  cpp16
       6.520 /6.500   /6.525/7.050,   % cp17  cpp17
       6.508 /8.600   /5.680/9.379,   % cp18  cpp18
       3.420 /9.379   /2.690/8.660,   % cp19  cpp19
       2.688 /7.000   /2.770/6.620,   % cp20  cpp20
       3.820 /4.350   /3.838/4.167,   % cp21  cpp21
       3.845 /2.840   /2.925/2.070,   % cp22  cpp22
       0.950 /2.070   /0.000/2.799    % cp23  cpp23
      }{% 
        \coordinate[mark coordinate,] (cp\c) at (\cpx,\cpy);
        \node[red,
              %label={[left]{\tiny cp\c}}
             ] at (cp\c) {\tiny{$\times$}};
        % CONTROLPOINT 2
        \coordinate[mark coordinate,] (cpp\c) at (\cppx,\cppy);
        \node[blue%
              %label={[left]{\tiny cpp\c}}
             ] at (cpp\c) {\tiny{$\times$}};
    }
    % All Beziercurves and helplines
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xplus using \x+1] in {1,...,23}
       {
        \draw[blue!50!black,line width=0.05mm] (p\x) .. controls (cp\x) and (cpp\x) .. (p\xplus);
        \draw[blue!100!black,line width=0.015mm] (p\x)--(cp\x)--(cpp\x)--(p\xplus);
       }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Visually set BCPs]